Total Derivative with product of two variables
I'm studying Topology and Differential Goemetry using the book, Topology, Geometry and Gauge Fields - Foundations (Second Edition) by Gregory L. Naber.
In chapter 5 Differentiable Manifolds and Matrix Lie Groups, section 5.5 Tangent Vectors and Derivatives, I came across a total derivative equation that I did not understand. In page 248, just below eqn 5.5.2, there is a snippet as given below.

For each $x \in U_{\epsilon}(0)$ and each $t$ in $[0,1]$, $tx \in U_{\epsilon}(0), \frac{d}{dt}g(tx)=D_i g(tx)x^i$.

Here $U_{\epsilon}(0)$ is an open ball at 0. $D_i$ is the partial derivative with respect to the $i$th co-ordinate. $x^i$ is the co-ordinate function. $g$ is a $C^\infty$ function on the manifold.
I am not quite understanding how this equation is arrived. If we consider single dimension (naming the point as $p$ in order to avoid confusion with $x$, which is used for the co-ordinate), the equation reduces to  $\frac{d}{dt}g(tp(x))=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}g(tp(x))x$
From my understanding of total derivative, $\frac{d}{dx}f(x,y)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$, the above equation doesn't make sense to me. Please help me understand how we arrived at the above equation in the book.
Apologies if it's a very naive question. I'm self learning and I cannot understand this with my calculus knowledge. Will be helpful if you can suggest any books for the same.

You have $f(t,x)=g(tx)$ and you proceed from there. Note that $d/dt$ is not a "total derivative".

Thanks for the clarification!

This is just the basic chain rule. Fix $x$ and consider $G(t)=g(tx)=g(h(t))$ with $h(t)=tx$. Then
$$G'(t) = Dg(h(t))h'(t) = \sum_i D_ig(h(t))h^i{}'(t) = \sum_i D_ig(tx)x^i.$$

Thanks for the clarification !

You're welcome. When you have no further questions, please accept the answer so that the question will go off the unanswered list.

Another query. When you do $G'(t)$, you are differentiating with respect to $t$. But $D_i$  differentiation with respect to coordinate functions. Why is that? (And again $h(t)$ is differentiated with respected to $t$, as expected per chain rule)

Because $g$ is a function of $x^1,\dots,x^n$. In classical notation, $$G'(t)=\sum_i \frac{\partial g}{\partial x^i}(h(t))\frac{dx^i}{dt}.$$ Here I'm writing $dx^i/dt$ instead of $h^i{}'(t)$.
